# How Does Deuteron Bombardment Work?

Tags: particle-accelerators

I've been reading about the discovery of Plutonium, and I'm confused about how absorbing a deuteron can convert Uranium-238 into Neptunium-238.

> Plutonium was first produced by Glenn T. Seaborg, Joseph W. Kennedy, Edward M. McMillan and Arthur C. Wohl by bombarding an isotope of uranium, uranium-238, with deuterons that had been accelerated in a device called a cyclotron. This created neptunium-238 and two free neutrons.

Source: https://education.jlab.org/itselemental/ele094.html

I understand why absorbing a neutron can convert Uranium-238 to 239, which is how the fissile Plutonium-239 was produced, but I've scoured the internet and can't find a single thing on deuteron bombardment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the “Newton’s cradle,” where one ball bearing strikes a line of ball bearings. The incoming projectile joins the group, and the ball way over at the other end of the line is ejected.

That’s (sort of) a reasonable model for “nucleon transfer” reactions. For example, the reason we have short-lived carbon-14 in the atmosphere is that cosmic-ray reactions make free neutrons, which find nitrogen-14 nuclei in the air and undergo

$$
\require{mhchem}
\ce{^{14}N + n \to p + ^{14}C}
$$

This nucleon transfer reaction is sometimes written $\ce{^{14}N(n,p)^{14}C}$, or even just as the incoming and outgoing pieces $\ce{(n,p)}$.

In your historical neptunium production, the reaction is
$\ce{^{238}U(^2H,2n)^{238}Np}$.  It may or may not be the case that the neutron which arrives on the deuteron is essentially a “spectator” and that the reaction is really $\ce{(p,n)}$ with extra steps.

Comment: A deuteron has twice the KE of a proton at the same speed, and I guess that may help the deuteron penetrate the nucleus. And having a neutron to eject gives the Pu a way to dispose of the excess KE.

Comment: So the proton and neutron in the deuteron are absorbed by the Uranium, which then becomes Neptunium, and an extra neutron is then ejected. Right?

Comment: @LeviHarrison Right. You could say that the intermediate state is some excited Np-240, which relaxes by emitting two neutrons.